# how to disable message box "Fail to create Empty Document " Message box in MFC SDI application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, sdi

I am using `VS2010` for my `MFC` SDI application.
In `MainFrame` Class in `OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)` function I am opening one dialog box and on `IDCANCLE` replay from the Dialog box I want to close my application.
I am using following code for the same in `onCreate` Function.

```
CTermsConditionDlg objTNCDlg;
if(!objTNCDlg.DoModal() == IDCANCLE){
return -1;
}
```

Now my Question is  after return Statement the application is Showing message box as shown in Image.
[image: Message on close]

I want to disable this message box and close my application.
Can any one help how can I do That.
Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you place this dialog so late into you initialization?
The problem is the SDI framework that relay on some initial things that are expected to run always. In this case it is always expected that the mainframe can be created. See code in CSingleDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile

Just place this code into InitInistance before LoadFrame or ProcessShellCommand is called. In this case you can easily terminate without disturbing problems.

Another Idea is to allow the creation of the window, but simply using a PostMessage(WM_CLOSE); In this case the initialization is done, everything is created and the application terminates again.

Comment: sorry for the late, as your 1st suggestion the code is already present in my app file. and about PostMessage() I am not getting any Idea where to put this code.

Comment: No. Your code is in the OnCreate handler. And this is wrong. Place it only in the InitInstance handler. Or use PostMessage and return success in OnCreate.